# PHP typecasting

Tags: php, types, casting

I was wondering what is the best way to typecast a value from one type to another.

Which variant should we use:

1. `intval($value);`
2. `settype($value, 'int')`
3. `(int)$value`

All of them produce same result.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
(int)$value
```

saves one function call compares to `intval($value)` and `settype($value, 'int')`.

And `(int)$value` is clean enough, so I prefer this way.

When you need to use `intval($value)` is that when you need to use the specified base for the conversion (the default is base 10). [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) accepts a second parameter for the base for the conversion.

Answer (score 7):

The answer here is to use whatever reads "cleaner" to you.  Any difference in speed is going to be so minor, that worrying about it is almost certain to cost you more time than you are liable to save.  What will save time, however, is having code that you can read and understand in the future.

There's an excellent article explain this very thing at [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

Answer (score 6):

`(int)$value` is much faster then other ways

Comment: "much faster" - please don't. Just because of such answers a lot of people think it is true

Comment: It's true. I've tested all ways 10 millions times and get the following results: int()$value - 2.7695989608765 s; intval($value) - 5.8383219242096 s; settype($value, 'int') - 8.035208940506 s. The calling functions in PHP is expensive

Comment: I agree it is faster, but when you'll have 10 millions casts in your code - you'll be in worse trouble than just deciding what to use - function or type hint. So for real life the difference doesn't matter at all (for hundreds of thousands it is negligible)

Comment: @IgorEvstratov [edit]ing your benchmark comparisons into your answer seems a sensible action.

Answer (score 2):

It can depend on what types you're converting. PHP is already designed to convert types on-the-fly. It can convert the string '5' into the integer value 5 or float 5.0 if necessary. That's just PHP's natural type converting, but there are ways to force similar behaviours.

In many cases intval() can actually be faster than (int) typecasting, especially in string-to-integer converting. But personally, as I also write C++, I use typecasting as it is more natural and neat to me. The results, however, vary slightly in different situations. I never thought of settype() to be promising, though.

Comment: If the type is dynamic, the only way to go is settype.