# Is there a ToStringBuilder for php?

Tags: php, tostring

In order to quickly write nice [`toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.tostring.php) methods in PHP I'm looking for something like the [`ToStringBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) class for java.

**Update**:
I'm not asking about how to use or implement [`toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.tostring.php). I'm asking about a powerfull helper like [`ToStringBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) for java. `ToStringBuilder` is a big time saver because it can figure out a lot of things by reflection by itself (e.g. collections, array, nested classes).

Comment: Yes you can. This is called `type casting` You can Google for this or check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857052/php-typecasting) In short you can do `echo (string) $int;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP doesn't really have a need for `ToStringBuilder`; in nearly all cases a simple `print_r()` or `var_dump()` will do the job of dumping any variable (including objects) for the purpose of debugging. To get a more exact and reproducible representation, you can use `var_export()`. For example:

```
class Test {
    private $x = 'hello';
    protected $y = 'world';
}

$t = new Test;

var_export($t);
var_dump($t);
print_r($t);
```

Output:

```
Test::__set_state(array(
   'x' => 'hello',
   'y' => 'world',
))

object(Test)#1 (2) {
  ["x":"Test":private]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  ["y":protected]=>
  string(5) "world"
}

Test Object
(
    [x:Test:private] => hello
    [y:protected] => world
)
```

Both `var_export()` and `print_r()` take a second parameter to return the string representation instead of printing their output. `var_dump()` doesn't have this feature, so you need another way:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($t);
$s = ob_get_clean();

echo "Object is $s\n";
```

See also: [`print_r()`](http://www.php.net/print_r) [`var_dump()`](http://www.php.net/var_dump) [`var_export()`](http://www.php.net/var_export)

**Old answer**

From my understanding of Java's implementation, this is a very minimalistic port to PHP I whipped up:

```
class ToStringBuilder
{
    private $o; // the object to build a string for
    private $h; // a hash of parameters

    public function __construct($obj)
    {
        $this->o = $obj;
        $this->h = array();
    }

    public function append($key, $value)
    {
        $this->h[] = "$key=$value";
        // you could also use this for a full representation of the PHP type
        // "$key=" . var_export($value, true)
        return $this; // make it chainable
    }

    // final serialization
    public function toString()
    {
        return get_class($this->o) . '@' . spl_object_hash($this->o) .
            '[' . join(',', $this->h) . ']';
    }

    // help method to avoid a separate $x = new ToStringBuilder() statement
    public function getInstance($obj)
    {
        return new self($obj);
    }
}
```

This is how you would use it in your own class:

```
class Person
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        // use ToStringBuilder to form a respresentation
        return ToStringBuilder::getInstance($this)
            ->append('name', $this->name)
            ->toString();
    }
}

$person = new Person("John Doe");
echo $person;
// Person@00000000708ab57c0000000074a48d4e[name=John Doe]
```

The serialization isn't very exact, because booleans will be represented either with an empty string or just `1`. This could be improved :)

Comment: @artragis Yeah, I've completely missed the point about `ToStringBuilder` so I rewrote the whole answer.

Comment: Thanks for the exHaustive answer! Actualy `print_r()`, `var_dump()` and  `var_export()` are perfect if you are looking for somehting like `ReflectionToStringBuilder`. If you want to restrict the ammount of data, the mentioned implementation for `ToStringBuilder` is a god startingpoint.

Comment: @BetaRide Thanks. Yeah, some of my variable dumps can get pretty messy, especially with recursion so being able to limit the output kinda makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick implementation, similar to the one you've linked but slightly different. The output closely resembles [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) (but not exactly the same) and span multiple lines:

```
<?php
class ToStringBuilder{
    private $str;

    public function __construct($my){
        $this->str = get_class($my) . "(\n";
    }

    public static function create($my){
        return new ToStringBuilder($my);
    }

    public function append($name, $var){
        $this->str .= "  " . $name . " => " . str_replace("\n", "\n  ", var_export($var, true)) . ",\n";
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->str . ")";
    }
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/9FJvpODp

---

To use it, refer to the following code:

```
class Person{
    private $name;
    private $age;
    private $hobbies;

    public function __toString(){
        return strval(ToStringBuilder::create($this)
                      ->append("name", $this->name)
                      ->append("age", $this->age)
                      ->append("hobbies", $this->hobbies)
                     );
    }

    public function __construct($name, $age, $hobbies){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->hobbies = $hobbies;
    }
}

echo new Person("hello", 18, array("swimming", "hiking"));
```