# GET variable and IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I have got problem with this simple `if` statement:

```
$type = $_GET['type'];
if ($type !== 1 || $type !== 2) {
    header('Location: payment.php');
    exit;
}
```

Only type *1* and *2* are allowed, but...

1. www.example/succeed.php?type=**1** - redirects back to payment.php
2. www.example/succeed.php?type=**2** - redirects back to payment.php
3. www.example/succeed.php?type=**3** - redirects back to payment.php

Last example is OK, but I don't know why it redirects too in first and second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!($type == 1 || $type == 2)) {
    header('Location: payment.php');
    exit;
}
```

This can be spoken as `Anything other than type is 1 or 2`

Answer (score 4):

`!==` is the identity operator; so it checks for type too.

But data in $_GET, $_POST, ... arrays are strings. So you need also to check against a string:

```
if ($type !== "1" && $type !== "2") /* ... */
```

Also checking if `$a !== $x && $a !== $y` will be always true (if `$x !== $y`). So use `||` here.

Comment: You also need to switch from OR to AND. `$x != 1 || $x != 2` is always true.

Comment: @Juhana true; didn't see that. Was too fast to see the second error, sorry.

Comment: @user2406937 better now?

Answer (score 0):

If you what you mean is only types with values 1 and 2 should be redirected you should try this code

```
if ($type === 1 || $type === 2) {
    header('Location: payment.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: No, only these types should not be redirected.

Comment: i see, how about this

    $type = (int)$_GET['type'];
    if ($type != 1 || $type != 2) {
        header('Location: payment.php');
        exit;
    }

Comment: `if (!($type == 1 || $type == 2))` - this works fine, but I want to ask you, what is _int_ here - `(int)$_GET['type'];`

Comment: (int) typecasts your value from string to integer..
you can search for the word typecasting in php in google or maybe you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857052/php-typecasting