# Casting to (int) vs. intval

Tags: php, integer

Are there any circumstances in which the outputs of

```
echo (int) $myStr;
```

and

```
echo intval($myStr);
```

would be different?

Comment: [This question explains it pretty well.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857052/php-typecasting)

Answer (score 1):

Not really big differences, it's just about what feels more comfortable for you. Only with intval you can change the base of the int, but if you work with decimal numbers, it does not have any real advantages compared to other (int).