# What does (string) mean in php/mysql prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, string, pdo, prepared-statement

Never seen this before. Was unable to find and explanation and I saw it the other day in a code, e.g.:

```
    $statement = $db->prepare("insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values (?, ?, ?)");
    $data = array((string) $var1, (string) $var2, (string) $var3);
    $statement->execute($data);
```

See this **(string)** part? Anyone to shed some light on it, please?

Comment: its not actually about prepared statement, its just type cast for the variable. here's the entry from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Sorry for the newb question. This answers it. Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP typecasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857052/php-typecasting)

Comment: The string cast looks unnecessary though. All values are treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR`

Answer (score 1):

It means everything that is written in $var1 and the others is converted to a String so the Programm can handle the input without getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple cast , here in the code , while the query is a string , so the (string) make sure that you are manipulating String , here is the PHP DOC:

```
(int), (integer) - cast to integer
(bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
(float), (double), (real) - cast to float
(string) - cast to string
(array) - cast to array
(object) - cast to object
(unset) - cast to NULL
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Example:

```
$int = 4;
$string = (string)$int; 
echo gettype($int); // output snteger
echo gettype($string); // output string
```

> In general , the meaning of type casting is to use the value of a
>   variable with different data type.

Comment: The even better answer! Thanks!!

Comment: Enjoy the great PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can bind parameter

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $var1, $var2, $var3);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Type specification chars**

i   *corresponding variable has type integer*

d   *corresponding variable has type double*

s   *corresponding variable has type string*

b   *corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets*

Comment: you can also do that step in the execute.. " input_parameters

    An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR. "  [source](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: this interface is mysqli, the OP is using PDO